# stream download very large file over bad connection

Tags: linux, shell, download, wget

I want to process a very large file (a few terabytes) as a stream. This file is accessible via http protocol and from a URL such as:

`http://example.com/some-file`

This command can do that:

```
wget -q -O - http://some-host/some-file | process-command
```

but if connection is lost, I must begin the process from the beginning.

`wget -c` cannot be used because I can't store the file due to large size.

Is there another command that can stream the remote file, while handling the required reconnects internally?

Answer (score 1):

The main idea of solving this problem is to download the file chunk by chunk and write somewhere the offset of the last downloaded chunk. For this, at first, we are specifying the chunk size. 
 
The chunk size as much is near the size of downloading file, performance is better but the **risk** of losing more data in connection corruption increases. My suggestion is around 10 percent of downloading file size. My experience says the speed of downloading by about `25` percent decreased using this method.

```
#!/bin/bash

URL="Your-URL"

content_length=$(curl -I $URL | grep -i 'Content-Length' | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '\r')

# In Bytes
chunk_size=10000000

while true; do
        offset=$(cat offset.txt | grep -Eo '[0-9]+')
        next_chunk=$((offset + chunk_size - 1))
        if [[ next_chunk -ge content_length ]]
        then
                curl -r $offset-$content_length --retry 10000 $URL > downloaded-chunk
                # In here you can do your process with the last downloaded chunk
                break
        fi
        curl -r $offset-$next_chunk $URL > downloaded-chunk
        # In here you can do your process with a downloaded chunk
        offset=$((next_chunk + 1))
        echo "Offset of the last chunk downloaded: $offset bytes"
        echo $offset > offset.txt
done
```

The size of the whole file is needed to know where we should have our range in using `curl` with the range option `-r`. The last chunk of data is not usually fitted in chunk size, this is handled by the `if` condition in the while.